# handle one to many relationship when updating db

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

how to handle the one to many relationshship.

Models:

```
public partial class Student
{
    public student()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int pkID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public partial class Course
{
    public int pkID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> fkStudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student  { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "pkID,Name")] Student student)
{
    student.Courses.Add(course); // How to fetch course from the Student/Create.cshtml and convert it to type Course
    db.Students.Add(student);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

View:

```
// Student/Create.cshtml
@model School.Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Tillbaka till lista", "Index")
</div>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Namn", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
         <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.DropDownList("Name", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Courses, "Kurs", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
         <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.DropDownList("Courses", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Courses, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
     </div>
}
```

The questions is how to fetch the courses data from the .cshtml and update db.
In the create function I only get the Name fetched, I know that one can use Request["Courses"], but then how to store it in the courses table?

Thank you!

Comment: Question is not clear, can you tell me in detail what you are looking for?

Comment: Ravi I want to add a courses for the student, when user adds a course I dont know how to get the selected value from the .cshtml to my post/create function?

Comment: so you are having single selection or multiple selection of Coure?

Comment: I need both, but for now let say single selection.

Comment: As you can see in my code : `[Bind(Include = "pkID,Name")] Student student` only brings back the property of the Student with out the course?

Comment: Your model is wrong, `Course` should not have a `fkStudentID` unless a `Course` can only be taken by one student.  This should be a `many-to-many` relationship

Comment: One student can have many courses, and course have only one student, I know that, it only an example I just want to know how retreive the courses selected value by user to my post/create function?

Answer (score 1):

For single selection of Course you add one column in Student class as 
`public int CourseId{get;set;}` and in view you put like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CourseId, new SelectList(Model.Courses, "pkID", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseId, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Now when you submit the form after selection of course you will get the selected courseid in `ActionResult` Create as `student.CourseId`.

Let me know if you need any more help

Comment: Thank you Ravi , and how about the multiple selection?

Answer (score 0):

Well... As mentioned above, the question itself is a bit unclear, but i will give it a shot.
In Relational databases the many relation knows about the one entity, not the other way around. This means that the primary key of the one-relation is the foreign keys in the many relation.

That said, in EF, when you make a container inside a class (or table), that container, being the many relationship, will have the one-relations primarykey and you can use it to find the specific many relation.

If this does´t answer your question, i recommend looking at this tutorial: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Hey Thank you, I have seen the tutorial, but it doesnt help. My Question is, I want to add course to the db, in order to do that I have to retrieve it from the .cshtml file where the user have selected it, So when the user add a course and hit create. The Post/create function is called, and here I only get the Student property  not the selected course, so how to get the selected course and add it to db?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple selection no need to add the new column as CourceId in Student class, you can do as below

```js
var i=0, html="";
$("#CourseId option:selected").each(function () {          
    var courseId = $(this).val();
    html += '<input type="hidden" name="Courses[' + i + '].pkID" id="Courses_' + i + '" value="' + courseId + '"/>';
                i = i + 1;
 });

$("#divDummy").html(html);
```

here assuming CourseId is the Id of your Dropdown and divDummy you take one empty div inside your form.
Now once you submit you will get the list of selected Course Id as student.Courses and above javascript should get called before submitting the form.

Let me know if you need anymore help.

Comment: Hm do I really need javascript to get multiple selected courses? shouldnt there be another way to get and update the related data in EF? I will try your suggested method, thank you for taking time helping me Ravi